# How to create a sitemap in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, sitemap

I am trying to create a sitemap in codeigniter. But I am facing some errors please help to fix this.
Here is the **sitemap.php** code

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'; ?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/</loc> 
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
     <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/contact</loc> 
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>


</urlset>
```

**Controller**

```
public function sitemap(){
            $data = "";//select urls from DB to Array
            header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
            $this->load->view("sitemap",$data);
        }
```

**ERROR**

```
 XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://localhost/hotel/index.php/sitemap.xml
Line Number 2, Column 1:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
^
```

Comment: Make sure that XML version line is at the very top of the file. Otherwise I'm using this Sitemap Library with codeigniter and it works really well http://github.com/evert/sitemap-php

Comment: yes.. XML version line is top

Comment: I mentioned it because in your error message it says line number 2.  And actually there is no reason to echo out the top xml line with php, just use the straight text.  And - not sure if its an issue -  i see that you are defining the charset as one thing in your header content type, and then another in the xml. Still would suggest using a library to help generate it.